# How to disable keyboard shortcut on web applications?

Tags: browser, website, javascript, web

I'm a Vimium user. So I want to operate everything in vim's way. But some web application override keyboard shortcuts. For example, gmail, JIRA, most of rich text editors and so on.
It is very stressful especially in the case that I voluntarily submit an html form.

Is there any good way to automatically disable keyboard shortcuts on perticular web applications?

Comment: Do you want to disable it by website or browser (and therefore application)?

Comment: Either way is okay if it works as a result.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to remap the command to another sequence that is not used on a given web site, assuming Vimium supports remapping. e.g:

```
:imap <C-m> <C-i>
```